# No Known Class- iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors

Could you please look at my code and tell me why I am doing wrong?

I am getting an error `"No known class for selector method "imageWithImage: (UIImage)image...."`

```
- (void)myMethod {

    UIImage *iconImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"male_small_0.png"];
    // I am having problem in the following line
    UIImage *iconImage2=[UIImage imageWithImage:iconImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(73.0, 73.0)];
 }

-(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage =UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `[self imageWithImage:...]` not `[UIImage imageWithImage...]`. The latter would imply that the method is a class method of `UIImage`, but it seems to be an instance method of the class that contains `myMethod`.

Comment: Could u please also look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486636/twitter-sheet-image-is-not-attached-ios

Comment: I will accept your answer. But system does not allow me right away, I have to wait 6 minutes.